# Duplicating contents of a VDI file to a larger one?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, filesystems, restore, crunchbang

My overall problem is that I filled my current virtual hard drive, so I want to move everything over to a larger VDI file and boot from that one instead.

If it matters, I have XP host and Crunchbang (based on Debian statler) guest, VirtualBox version 4.1.2r73507.

I first tried [this guide](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2010/05/expand-vdi-virtualbox/), but after dd'ing the contents of /dev/sda1, gparted couldn't tell that there was a smaller partition on the larger disk. But, I did have all of /dev/sda1 copied to /dev/sdb1, the only problem was that /dev/sdb1 thought it only had 8 GB, not 32.

Then I discovered [fsarchiver](http://fsarchiver.org), which claims to be able to restore archive files to larger partitions, so I created an archive of /dev/sdb1 with

```
fsarchiver savefs -A /media/sf_C_DRIVE/temp/backup.fsa /dev/sdb1
```

Then I wiped out /dev/sdb1 with gparted (reformatted the whole thing as ext4) and restored the archive file with

```
fsarchiver restfs /media/sf_C_DRIVE/temp/backup.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sdb1
```

And according to df, I think that worked. It shows roughly the same number of blocks used, but a much smaller % used. But, when I go into the virtual machine settings and switch the larger drive in as Primary Master, I can't boot (not even GRUB)

---

To make things worse, I decided to boot the machine from a LiveCD, clear /dev/sdb1 again, recreate the archive (this time from the real /dev/sda1), and restfs /dev/sdb1. Unfortunately, I wasn't paying attention, so I wiped /dev/sda1. Without Guest Additions on the LiveCD, I can't access the fsa file in C:\temp to restore the image to either VDI file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copying, just make the existing virtual drive file larger then boot the vm ( possibly from a livecd ) and add/extend partitions.

Comment: I'd love to be able to do that. Do you have any specific instructions? Everything I found said it's not possible.

Comment: I don't use virtualbox, but it is quite simple with other virtual machines like vmware, qemu or xen, so I can't imagine that virtualbox can't do it.

Comment: BTW, you were right. Buried in the manual is vboxmanage modifyhd (virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi)

Comment: @NateParsons here is the guide: http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/

Nutshell:  it needs gparted installed as an .iso for you to run in VBox. Make a new linux VM and use gparted.iso as the installation media, this runs its own mini-virtualmachine where u can attach your .vdi and make it bigger.